# Run-time error 13 trying to change variables to an array

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

This is my first day of coding and I am trying to add the values of cells A1 to A20 to an array, it is giving me a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" on line 4.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Dothis()
Dim test() As String
Dim element As Variant
test() = Range("A1:A20").Value
For Each element In test
    If (element > 10) Then element = element + 1
    End
Next element

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: [Range("A1:A20").Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193(v=office.14).aspx) returns an array of type Variant. You are trying to assign it to an array of type String. End statement is not required here. Have a look at the [If Then Else](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx) syntax

Comment: I am trying to check if each number in the array is greater than 10. If it is I'll add 1 to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this:

```
Sub Dothis()
   Dim test() As String
   Dim element As Variant
   Dim element2 As Variant

   Dim i As Integer
   element = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A20")

   For i = 20 To 10 Step -1
   element(i, 1) = element(i, 1) + 1
   Debug.Print element(i, 1)
   Next i
   element2 = element
   For i = 1 To 20
   Debug.Print element2(i, 1)
   ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B20") = element2
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much I understand the logic here but why did you have to define "rng As Range" and what if I had a huge swathe of numbers in the row and I didn't want to check the end of the column is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Ahmed Touk I generally define range variables and then use it. Later on during testing somehow I did not use it. It is redundant now. I shall edit my post. If my answer meets your requirement then here in Stack Overflow saying thanks is by ticking a mark below lower triangle and accepting the Answer.

Comment: @Ahmed Touk Regarding your second point if it is only one row you can transpose from row to column. Please put a new question for that showing representative sample data so that your requirements are fully understood.